# I am getting this error while using smote

Tags: python, imblearn, smote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lquNP.png)

```
# apply SMOTE to tackle class imbalance
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(kind = "regular", k=1)
X_tr,y_tr = sm.fit_sample(X_train,y_train)
print(X_tr.shape)
print(y_tr.shape)
```

Please help me on this matter

Comment: Don't know which version of imblearn you're using but the latest version doesn't seem to take any parameter called "kind": https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/edf6eae2c00f7fa6d76ee381f5b625155061a725/imblearn/over_sampling/_smote/base.py#L212

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Answer (score 0):

`SMOTE` oversampling algorithm do not have a parameter called `kind` as you suggest, as far the [documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html).

> class imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE(*, sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=None, k_neighbors=5, n_jobs=None)

If you mean the kind of oversampling to, do, `minority`, `not minority` etc, that parameter is the `sampling_strategy` and default to `auto`.

```
sm = SMOTE(sampling_strategy = "minority")
```